# Sent an Email just once to the admin help?

Tags: magento-1.7

Here is the issue; I am creating a web service using API to connect to something else. And I want to handle an error in case the path does not work but I want to notify the admin for this issue by email and I want that just once because on the web may be 1000 user per day this would be crazy to sent 1000 emails.

Here is the code:

```
$errorMessage = 0;
try {$client = new SoapClient('http://xxxxxxxxxxx');}

catch(Exception $e) {$exceptionMessage = $e->getMessage();

if ($exceptionMessage) {

$errorMessage = 1;

echo 'Display the error';

if($errorMessage = 1){

  echo "Send an email to admin";
  $errorMessage = 0;

} else {
  echo 'Email just sent to the admin';

    }

  } 
}
```

It looks that id does not work this way. What I was thinking is to do that via database to insert a value like 1 and then switch it to 0. I don't know if you guys have a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a stateless language and will not persist the value of a variable across multiple executions or web requests. You will need to store this value in the database. I would recommend storing the current time stamp when you send the message, then check against that and if it's been 24 hrs or so since the message was last sent you'll send again and update the time stamp.

Comment: Yes that was what i did i choose to use DB for this purpose,Thank you for your answer. :)